# Hercules DJ Console RMX w/o Software = Brick?

Tags: dj

So I bought a "Hercules DJ Console RMX" at a yard sale for $5 - but it didn't come with any software.

Now I found out you can't just use this as a mixer, you need a copy of "Virtual DJ" to run it at all, which is $100 I don't wanna spend.

Is there any free software that supports this hardware or did I just buy a brick? Can't it be used somehow as a generic MIDI controller?

Comment: You can get drivers from http://ts.hercules.com/. If you can find the right ones for your computer and OS, do so and see if it is recognised as a midi device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mixxx](http://mixxx.org) is free, open source DJ software which [supports](http://mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/hardware_compatibility) the [Hercules DJ Console RMX](http://mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/hercules_dj_console_rmx) (and the [Hercules DJ Console RMX 2](http://mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/hercules_dj_console_rmx_2)).

> The Hercules DJ Console RMX is a USB MIDI controller with a built in
>   sound card. It is compatible with Mixxx versions 1.6.1+herc and later.
>   Both audio and MIDI works in Linux (from kernel ~2.6.27+), Windows
>   (XP, Vista, 7), and MAC OS X (10.4.11 (Tiger)/ 10.5.x (Leopard)/
>   10.6.x (Snow Leopard) 32-bit). It has been discontinued in favor of the
>   Hercules DJ Console RMX 2 which is USB MIDI class compliant and requires
>   no special driver.

As the controller is quite old, the page does not appear to have been updated for newer OSes. The manufacturer's driver page indicates continued compatibility with Windows 10 and OS X 10.10:

> Drivers for MAC OS X and Windows can be found on the [Hercules support
>   page](https://support.hercules.com/en/product/djconsolermx-en/). Same package for both Audio and MIDI.

And, if you are a linux user:

> The audio device on the RMX is USB-audio class compliant and works
>   well with the ordinary [ALSA USB-audio driver](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-usb-audio). This should work out of
>   the box on most distributions. [...] Hercules has released a common
>   MIDI-driver for their DJ controllers.

For further details on that MIDI-driver you should refer to Mixxx's [Hercules Linux kernel module](http://mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/hercules_linux_kernel_module) wiki page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer. I've installed it now on Windows 10 64bit, where it's working flawless, will try Linux too.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [data sheet](http://www.hercules.com/download/DJConsoleRmx_ProductSheet_2008_04_Long_ENG.pdf).

Page 8 states it cannot be used without a computer; it is a virtual mixing deck.

However it also states on the same page that is **can** be used with other DJ software. It's effectively just a standard MIDI controller.

So you will need a computer to provide power and MIDI signals over the USB socket, but in addition if you can get hold of some free or open DJ-ing software you may be able to use it. Don't abandon it yet; you might be able to get some hints with a general search for DJ forums, etc.